# WP dashboard messed up

Tags: wp-admin, dashboard

It seems like CSS issue, but it is not persistent, sometimes works, sometimes not, however the site itself is working just fine, but I hardly can use the dashboard.
This is not a duplicate, because the others solution does not work here.
It is a fresh installation of WP, I tried reinstalling the whole wp, tried other themes a well, everything is updated, here it is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that if you enable the Network tab in your browser Diagnostics screen (usually F9, but right-click and select 'inspect'). you will see that a CSS file is not getting loaded for some reason.

This is probably a theme issue of not properly loading the CSS. Could also be a caching issue; perhaps the CSS file is cached and needs to be refreshed.

But looking at the items 'requested' via the Developer's Network tab will probably show a '404' on a particular CSS request. You can then look at that request and determine it's "caller" (the code file that tried to load the CSS), and troubleshoot from there. As mentioned, I suspect it will be a CSS request made by the theme.

You could try a different theme; or clear your browser cache. Browser cache is likely if you are developing the theme and make changes to the CSS file. There are ways to add a parameter to the CSS request to 'bust' the cache, forcing the CSS file to be loaded from source rather than cache. You may also need to disable any caching plugin you have.

Comment: No css is loaded in the Network tab

Comment: If CSS is 404'd on the Developer's Network tab, then your theme is not properly loading the CSS file. Ask your theme's support page for help.

Answer (score 0):

It was a DNS problem, It was a freshly installed site, on a brand new domain. the dns serves was not fully set up. Problem solved by time.